# Virtual Lightning channels for high availability

Tags: lightning-network, ln-node-reliability

I've recently reread Rene Pickhardt's [draft proposal for Virtual Channels](https://www.rene-pickhardt.de/index.html%3Fp=2131.html).

One benefit of virtual channels, as I understand it, is that they would allow a single entity to run multiple nodes while leveraging the full capacity of all nodes (both inbound and outbound). This would be a possible way for entities to run a highly-available, perhaps geographically distributed, cluster of nodes.

Did anything come of this idea? Are there other strategies for high availability which have gained more adoption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are currently [ideas being discussed to have Gossip v2](https://lists.linuxfoundation.org/pipermail/lightning-dev/2019-July/002065.html) which would be a bit more private. The reason why I mention this is that currently every channel is bound to a UTXO to prevent spam. In Gossip v2 one would not have to tie a channel to an UTXO but one might be allowed to announce several channels if one can proof control over an UTXO. the Amounts of the announced channel would not have to add up exactly to the UTXO and one would not have to point to them. I think with such a Gossip Protocol It would be much easier to publicly announce such virtual channels which are not really backed by anything.

While I heard people talking about similar concepts and ideas I haven't seen such constructions in the wild.